# WinUI3 MVVM binding PointerMoved event in ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

I am trying to bind a PointerModed event on a view page to my ViewModel, but the event is not firing for an unknown reason.

**Page XAML**

```
<Page 
......
PointerMoved="{x:Bind ViewModel.Mouse_PointerMoved}">
```

**Page ViewModel**

```
public void Mouse_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //some code
}
```

> I had no trouble binding the same event on the XAML backend, but it did not work when I bind in ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you didn't set the `Background` of the root element. At least, it needs to be `Transparent`.

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="WinUI3App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3App"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    PointerMoved="{x:Bind ViewModel.Page_PointerMoved}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="Transparent" />
</Page>
```

Just let me tell you that you should try to avoid UI code in your ViewModel. `PointerMove` event in this case.

Comment: The grid background is not relevant to the issue at hand. As you suggested, I will simply move the event from the ViewModel code.

Comment: Without explicitly setting the `Background`, pointer events won't get fired.